# telerik radwindow : Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

I have two user controls that contain the telerik radwindow.

When I try to open second window on first window button click, I get the below exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Comment: Hmm i have occassionally experienced this also, and the best i have been able to tell it is related to a mouse event, and it appears to originate solely from within the telerik component, but i have never been able to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having the problem described here:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/window/exception-quot-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-quot.aspx